# jquery ui draggable limit so cannot be pulled over another div

Tags: jquery, user-interface

can i limit the draggable function to jump down if div is already there or just a limit?
   is there any method?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".a").draggable();
 });
```

[here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/5EChH/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to use sortables? Here is an example of how to use those:

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div class="a" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;background: red;"></div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="a" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;background: green;">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="a" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;background: blue;">
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").sortable();
});
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/5EChH/1/

Comment: not sortable,i just wanna limit the div so cannot be pulled over another div with same class

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery UI Draggable Collision](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquidragcollide/).  It's a plugin that provides collision events to your draggable elements.  You should be able to take care of all of your issues with this.

Comment: Or if you don't want ui/collision combined and just want the collision plugin, you can get it by itself here. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/